# Fpdf PHP páginação

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, fpdf

Estou com dificuldades pra realizar uma paginação.

Recebe os dados do relatório em formato de array, ai tenho que fazer um foreach pra varrer os dados, acontece que estou fazendo isso dentro de 2 for, e os dados ficam repetindo, como resolvo já tentei usar alguns break, mas não funciona ?

```
namespace Helpers;

require_once 'Fpdf/fpdf.php';
require_once 'FormataData.php';
require_once 'C:xampp/htdocs/pim_dev/DAO/EstoqueDAO.php';

use \FPDF;
class RelatorioPorEntrada  {


    public function gerar($dataOne, $dataTwo, $dados)
    {


        $logo = "c:xampp/htdocs/pim_dev/content/img/relat4.png";
        $data = date('j/m/Y');
        $por_pagina = 3;
        $row = count($dados);
        $paginas = ceil($row/$por_pagina);
        $pdf = new FPDF("P", "cm", "A4");

        $linha_atual = 0;
        $inicio = 0;




        for($x=1; $x<=$paginas; $x++)
        {
            $inicio = $linha_atual;
            $fim = $linha_atual + $por_pagina;
            if($fim > $row) $fim = $row;
            $pdf->Open();
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->SetFont("arial");
            $pdf->Image($logo, 0,0);
            $pdf->SetTitle("Relatorio");

            $pdf->Ln(1);
            $pdf->SetFontSize(14);
            $pdf->Cell(0,3, utf8_decode("Relatório Mensal"),0,0,"C");
            $pdf->SetFontSize(10);
            $pdf->Cell(0, 5, utf8_decode("Página $x de $paginas"),0, 0, "R");
            $pdf->Ln(1);
            $pdf->Cell(0,3, "Data:".$data,0,0,"E");
            $pdf->Ln(1);
            $dateFormat = new FormataData();
            $novaDataone = $dateFormat->dateToBr($dataOne);
            $novaDataTwo = $dateFormat->dateToBr($dataTwo);
            $pdf->Cell(0,3,utf8_decode("Periodo:".$novaDataone." "."até ".$novaDataTwo),0,0,"E");
            $pdf->SetFontSize(8);
            $pdf->Ln(3);
            $pdf->SetDrawColor(57,181,74);
            $pdf->SetFillColor(57,181,74);
            $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 255, 255);
            $pdf->Cell(1,1, "ID", 1,0,"C",true);
            $pdf->Cell(3,1, "Produto", 1,0,"C",true);
            $pdf->Cell(3,1, "Date de Entrada", 1,0,"C",true);
            $pdf->Cell(2,1, utf8_decode("Valor Unitário"), 1,0,"C",true);
            $pdf->Cell(2,1, "Quantidade", 1,0,"C",true);
            $pdf->Cell(2,1, "Valor Total", 1,0,"C",true);
            $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);




            for($i=$inicio; $i<$fim; $i++)
            {
                 foreach($dados as $values)
               {
                    $pdf->Ln(1);
                    $pdf->Cell(1,1, $dados[0], 1,0,"C");
                    $pdf->Cell(3,1, $dados[1], 1,0,"C");
                    $pdf->Cell(3,1, $dados[2], 1,0,"C");
                    $pdf->Cell(2,1, $dados[3], 1,0,"C");
                    $pdf->Cell(2,1, $dados[4], 1,0,"C");
                    $pdf->Cell(2,1, $dados[5], 1,0,"C");


                }


                $linha_atual++;
            }

        }
        return $pdf->Output("relatorio.pdf", "I");
    }


}
```

[image: distribuicao do texto]

Comment: Seria interessante adicionar mais conteúdo pois esta bem vaga sua pergunta

Comment: É uma paginação antes de gerar o pdf.

Comment: Meu objetivo é gerar um arquivo pdf sem quebras de conteúdo. Quando começo o  texto em uma pagina tenho de terminar nessa página.

Comment: Edite a pergunta adicionando informações

Comment: Acho que entendi + ou -. 
você deseja que fique uma tabela por página? 
Se for isso e  no Fpdf você puder utilizar CSS na configuração do documento, para gerar o PDF, como no exemplo do DOMPDF que "Transforma HTML e CSS em PDF", você poderia utilizar as propriedade page-break-after e page-break-before dependendo da sua necessidade. Espero que seja isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia tentar utilizar o **SetAutoPageBreak**

```
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,10);
```

Veja se te ajuda.

Link da documentação: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setautopagebreak.htm

**Em relação a quebra de conteúdo:**

O problema é que no método Cell() chamado (MultiCell()) o FPDF adiciona uma nova página se a posição Y atual + a altura da nova célula for maior que a altura da página permitida.

A altura da página padrão parece ser 297, com SetAutoPageBreak() você abstrai 150 dele. Então, quando Y + cell_height é maior que 147, você sempre obtém uma nova página ao chamar loop das paginas.

Para evitar isso, você precisa chamar AddPage() por você mesmo. Adicione esta verificação no seu loop:

Vocô pode substituir seu `$pdf->AddPage()` pela informação abaixo.

```
$x = $this->width;
$y = $this->pdf->GetY();

if (($y + $this->line_height) >= 147) {
    $this->pdf->AddPage();
    $y = 0; // é sua margin top
}
```

Removendo o `$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,10);`

Comment: Ela quebra automaticamente a pagina sem quebar o conteudo do bloco ??

Comment: @alexjosesilva Quebra automaticamente com base na distancia do bottom setado como exemplo 10.

Comment: coloco a chamada no fim do loop...ou antes de fpdf->output ?

Comment: @alexjosesilva coloca após o $pdf->Open();

Comment: Tem como o PHP informar o espaço ocupado na página ou o espaço que resta na pagina antes de chegar no rodape ??

Comment: @alexjosesilva Se você der uma olhada na documentação ira ver que o segundo parâmetro é o identificador da distancia com o final da página. Se te ajudou a solução marque como resolvida.

Comment: o conteudo esta sendo quebrado no fim da pagina. O que devo fazer é uma paginação: saber quantas linhas foram geradas e quantos faltam. Assim posso evitar a quebra do bloco do texto!

Comment: Estou editando a resposta

Comment: @alexjosesilva veja se ficou mais claro e funcional para você

Comment: otimo..assim mesmo..perfeito: Parabens!!!

Comment: fico feliz em ter ajudado @alexjosesilva